# Screenshot to open application

Tags: android, imageview, screenshot

I am trying to use a screenshot of a video as a shortcut to open that video.

Anyone know an existing app before I start hacking?

Comment: pls be clear in what you want to do and what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a local video, there is a great tool that built-in in Android. You can use it like below and write it to a file you want:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                fileName.getAbsolutePath(), Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        if(bitmap != null) {
            FileOutputStream thumbnail_out = new FileOutputStream(thumbnail);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, thumbnail_out);
            thumbnail_out.close();
        }
```